# How do I apply format to dataframe with multilevel column index when using set_table_styles()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multilevel column index.

```
   letters       
       Pct.  Freq.
a  0.938160  13229
b  0.033969    479
c  0.027870    393
d  0.000000      0
e  0.000000      0
```

I want to use `df.style.set_table_styles(my_style).format(my_format)`
Where

```
my_format = {
    'Pct.': '{:.2%}'.format,
    'Freq.': '{:,}'.format
}
```

But I can't figure out how to write the mapping for `my_format` to access the lower levels and format the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tuple as the `key`

```
df.style.format(formatter = {('letters','Pct.'): '{:.2%}'.format})
```